# How to copy text from a multiple column-range into 1 column (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to basically compile cells that contain strings from a multi-column range into 1 column (see the link below for a more visual explanation).

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/....](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zBQhzI_zmv257KYiF2lKAQKhg5uuYNCk7KMqCoEdBzM/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried to `QUERY` the data but obviously, that doesn't quite condense the strings into 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B5:H),,COLUMNS(B5:H))),"  ",""))
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but requires copying down:

```
=textjoin(", ",1,B5:H5)
```